# New lines in array index

Tags: php, arrays, opencart

We are having trouble removing certain items from the cart in our customised and old version of opencart. In our website the cart is stored in session as an array like this:

```
[product_id:options] => $quantity
```

The problem seems to be that part of the option data contains new lines which means the session data looks like this.

```
Array
(
    [808: yyuu

.3959: yyuu

.3959] => 1
)
```

When a customer tries to remove products the key is sent to the server but it does not find the array key

```
808: yyuu

.3959: yyuu

.3959
```

as an index.

Can new line characters be used as an array index?

Comment: What version of OC is that? It looks really very old...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option you have is to change it to current behavior - where the options are no longer in readable way (array) but they are encoded into `Base64` like this (`system/library/cart.php::add()`, OC v. 1.5.5.1):

```
if (!$option) {
    $key = (int)$product_id;
} else {
    $key = (int)$product_id . ':' . base64_encode(serialize($option));
}
```

Then the key of product in cart with options looks like this

> 123:SDFD/GHDS%RFW$ET35&TSF^WRT3@5YIWFHLDSFW/ETE4=

The encoded options can be then obtained from such key by this code:

```
$product = explode(':', $key);
$product_id = $product[0];

// Options
if (isset($product[1])) {
    $options = unserialize(base64_decode($product[1]));
} else {
    $options = array();
}
```

Such changes would have to be implemented probably on more places through system library `Cart`.

Now it shouldn't be a problem to find these keys within the arrays as it will never contain white caracters (`\n\r\t\s`).